# React Native - Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication

Tags: android, react-native

When I run a simple "AwesomeProject" app as stated in React Native Getting started page, the app runs on Nexus6 API 23 but [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgGSB.png)  is shown. I also tried the following methods to solve the error:

- adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081, but doesn't work.
- "react-native start" in command line before running the app but it does not show anything after "Loading Dependency Graph, done."
- Running it on Nexus5X API 25 but still error occurs.
  How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that by typing:
react-native start --port 8081
in the command line, and running app by opening another cmd shell, I was able to run the app successfully. Thanks.

Comment: Before you run this command specifying the port number, which port number did it use? You can tell from the message it outputs: Running packager on port xxxx, after running 'react-native start'. In my case, it is 8081, so I wonder that is the reason this solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. using gitbash and cd to directory of RN project, typing npm run clean.
2. Wipe iOS/android build folder and all cache, node_modules.
3. react-native run-android ==> and it worked for me.